# IIS Architecture: What signals w3wp.exe to start?

Tags: iis

What is the mechanism by which the w3wp.exe process knows to start?

Any IIS gurus know the specifics about the internals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a handler registered with the IIS that spawns it when a resource supported by it is requested and delegates the request to the worker process.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the handler?

Comment: Aspnet_isapi.dll - IIS script mappings associate ASP.NET file types with this ASP.NET ISAPI extension that runs inside Inetinfo.exe. It is responsible for forwarding requests to the ASP.NET worker process through an asynchronous named pipe. It also starts the worker process and performs health monitoring. The ISAPI extension contains no managed code and performs no request processing itself.

Check out this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302436.aspx